# How to add breadcrumb?

Tags: breadcrumbs, taxonomy-terms

How can I add breadcrumb to a page in my attendance module.

I have used the following hook, but it changed the breadcrumb for all pages in other modules also.

```
function attendance_init() {
// set the breadcrumb
$breadcrumb = array();
$breadcrumb[] = l('Home', '<front>');
$breadcrumb[] = l('People', 'group/node/'. arg(2) .'/people');
$breadcrumb[] = l('Attendance', 'group/node/'. arg(2) .'/people/attendance');
drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);         

}
```

Comment: "to a page" - but to which page? Is it a specific node with a given node id or something else?

Comment: this is bound to happen with `hook_init`, like the posts below choosing the appropriate condition for page helps decide the hook better.. perhaps if you could edit your query to describe the specific case we could suggest you the hook

Comment: yep, please describe the use case better!

Answer (score 1):

Could you get what you want from the [Custom Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) module?

> Allows administrators to set up parametrized breadcrumb trails for any
>   node type. This allows CCK-style node types to have "Home > User Blog
>   >2005 > January" style breadcrumbs on the node view page itself, synchronizing cleanly with custom views or pathauto aliases.
>   Breadcrumb visibility can be customized via a php snippet.

Answer (score 1):

About breadcrumb If you want to change in a node you can use hook_node_view to change breadcrumb an you can check $node->tyoe

```
function hook_node_view($node)
{
   if($node->type=="page")
    {
       drupal_set_breadcrumb();
    }
}
```

if you want to use it in a page
you can check arg or $_GET['q'] in any of hook_page
Hope it can help you

Comment: You forgot to define the $breadcrumb array mentioned in the question, and passing it to [drupal_set_breadcrumb](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_set_breadcrumb/7). So at the end, it should look like this: `drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);`.